# Using void (*)() pointers for other functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, language-lawyer

Is it legal to access pointers to functions with varying argument lists in via a `void (*f)()` pointer? The program below compiles without warnings with gcc and appears to run correctly, but is it legal C?

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

typedef void    funp();

static  void    funcall( funp* F, int args, double x)
{
    switch( args)
    {
        case    0:  F();    break;
        case    1:  F(x);   break;
    }
}

static  void    fun0( void)
{
    printf( "zero\n");
}

static  void    fun1( double x)
{
    printf( "one\t%f\n", x);
}

int main( )
{
    funcall( (funp*)fun0, 0, 17.0);
    funcall( (funp*)fun1, 1, 17.0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compiled this with

```
gcc -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu11 -O2 -o ./funp funp.c
```

It would be undefined behavior if the `nargs` parameter didn't match the number of arguments the function took, but is it legal if there is a match?

Comment: Not the answer to your specific question, but the common approach is to just have a function pointer which accepts a `void*` parameter and then interpret it differently depending on the actual implementation. This parameter can then be anything from `NULL` to a pointer to a struct with a dozen of parameters. If the caller must know the number, type and the order of parameters, the whole idea becomes less useful in practice.

Comment: The spacing in the code you've posted is making me irrationally angry.

Comment: It would be good practice to remove the casts from `main`.  In general, such casts may cause the compiler to suppress diagnostics for incorrect conversions .

Comment: Regardless of whether this sort of construction is strictly *legal*, I'd argue there are cleaner ways to accomplish the same thing (for example, have `fun0` take an argument and just ignore it).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: My initial impression, in the first second of seeing the code block, just based on the spacing, was that it looked like assembly language (based on multiple tab-stopped columns, like asm would use for `mnemonic   op1, op2`).  I was like "this was from HNQ, why haven't I seen this in the active asm questions list?"  I don't like this spacing for C, either!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In this particular case, the calls are legal.

Section 6.7.6.3p15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) spells out what makes two function type compatible (relevant part in bold):

> For two  function  types  to  be  compatible,  both  shall  specify 
>   compatible  return  types. Moreover,  the  parameter  type  lists,  if
>   both  are  present,  shall  agree  in  the  number  of parameters  and
>   in  use  of  the  ellipsis  terminator;  corresponding  parameters 
>   shall  have compatible types.  **If one type has a parameter type list
>   and the other type is specified by a function  declarator  that  is 
>   not  part  of  a  function  definition  and  that  contains  an  empty
>   identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis
>   terminator and the type of each parameter  shall  be  compatible  with
>   the  type  that  results  from  the  application  of  the default
>   argument promotions.**  If one type has a parameter type list and the
>   other type is specified by a function definition that contains a
>   (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree  in  the  number 
>   of  parameters,  and  the  type  of  each  prototype  parameter  shall
>   be compatible  with  the  type  that  results  from  the  application 
>   of  the  default  argument promotions  to  the  type  of  the 
>   corresponding  identifier.   (In  the  determination  of  type
>   compatibility  and  of  a  composite  type,  each  parameter  declared
>   with  function  or  array type is taken as having the adjusted type
>   and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the
>   unqualified version of its declared type.)

So you have a `typedef`  with type:

```
void()
```

And functions with type:

```
void(void)
void(double)
```

The two function definitions don't use ellipsis (`...`) so that satisfies the fist condition.  For the second condition, let's look at what the **default argument promotions** are.  Those are specified in section 6.5.2.2p6:

> If  the  expression  that  denotes  the  called  function  has  a 
>   type  that  does  not  include  a prototype,  the  integer  promotions
>   are  performed  on  each  argument,  and  arguments  that have  type
>   `float` are  promoted  to `double`.  These  are  called  the *default 
>   argument promotions*.

The first function has no arguments, so it is compatible.  The second function has a single `double` argument, which matches the default argument promotions, so it is also compatible.

To give some more examples, the following functions would also be compatible:

```
void f1(long);
void f2(int);
```

But these would not:

```
void f3(float);
void f4(char);
void f5(short);
```

Answer (score 13):

As another answer notes, the code you showed is valid C *today*. But that may change at any point in the future, due to the use of a function type with no parameter list.

> ## **6.11 Future language directions**
>
> ### **6.11.6 Function declarators**
>
> [1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.6p1) The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not
> prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent
> feature.

An obsolescent feature is one that is subject to removal in future standard versions. So if you wish your code to be future proof, it's best to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks. Alas, saying this feature is obsolescent seems a bit harsh to me.

Comment: This section is specifically referring to function *declarators*. It's saying that declaring a function as `void f();` is obsolescent; it's not saying that the existence of the function type `void()` or the pointer type `void (*)()` is obsolescent. (I don't know what the underlying intent was, but the literal text only talks about declarators.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica This way the above code for poor programmers generics is still valid, but K&R style function declarations (`int main()`) aren't anymore. Many omit the `void` here, thinking this would mean "no arguments", although it means " unspecified number" when used as a standalone declaration and "no arguments *but no prototype*" if used as part of a function definition. In both cases, the compiler won't warn if you accidentally pass arguments and in the second case it's definitely undefined behavior.

Comment: @user2357 - A declarator is  a syntactic construct used to create declarations. And some types are derived from declarators. `void (*)()` contains a function declartor on top of a pointer declarator. How exactly is the type going to continue to exist without the syntax to create it!??

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: `void (*)()` does not contain a function declarator. Declarators declare things (see 6.7.6). `void (*)()` doesn't declare anything. `void (*)()` is a type name.

Comment: @user2357 -  Fine, I'll play along. Even if we ignore the notion of a "derived-declarator-type-list" How do you propose to use this type without declaring anything that designates it? You can't `typedef void (*ptr)()`. That'd be a declaration.

Comment: True! I was not quite clear on the distinction between declarators and declarations when I posted my initial comment; upon further examination of the standard, I see that `typedef void (*ptr)()` does contain a function declarator, though the declaration declares a typedef for a pointer type. Removing no-parameter-list function declarators makes it almost impossible to do anything with such types, even if you keep the syntax for the type name, so the intent probably is for such types to go away entirely.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in @StoryTeller's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61934440/5264491), the use of function declarators with empty parentheses is an obsolescent feature, but it can be avoided:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>

typedef void    funp(void);

static  void    funcall( funp* F, int args, double x)
{
    switch( args)
    {
        case    0:
            F();
            break;
        case    1:  
            {
                typedef void fn(double);
                ((fn *)F)(x);
            }
            break;
    }
}

static  void    fun0( void)
{
    printf( "zero\n");
}

static  void    fun1( double x)
{
    printf( "one\t%f\n", x);
}

int main( void )
{
    funcall( (funp*)fun0, 0, 17.0);
    funcall( (funp*)fun1, 1, 17.0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT: Changed parameter list of `main` to `void` for compliance.

---

In answer to the query:

> "Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters" would seem to mean that the types of funp and of fun1 are incompatible. Is it ok to cast?

The answer is yes, it is OK to cast. From C11 draft [6.3.2.3 para 8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8):

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

In the code, the pointer to `fun1` has been converted to a different function pointer type in the call to `funcall`, and converted back to the original type within `funcall` so can be used to call `fun1`.

Comment: However from dbush's extract from the spec, "Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters" would seem to mean that the types of funp and of fun1 are incompatible. Is it ok to cast?

Comment: @dmuir the required compatibility is between *the function being called* and *the expression of the function call*.  It doesn't matter if there was some different type used to transport the function pointer before we got to the function call expression.

Comment: @M.M Huh, there are two conditions, the first being about the types (which this violates) and the second one about the expressions (fine). However, OPs code should to me reading even be OK in future, since the typedef is no function declaration and thus legitimate. However the function declaration `main` in this answer isn't :p

Comment: @larkey it's not clear to me what you mean by your "the first", could you provide a standard quote and/or elaborate. The program in this answer is well-defined

Comment: @M.M I meant the first extract dbush cited, namely 6.7.6.3p15, speaks about the types with 6.5.2.2p6 speaking about the expression. The declaration of `main` here misses the `void` argument which is a obsolete feature as cited by StoryTeller.

Comment: I've fixed the `main` parameter list (never noticed it previously!) and added stuff about function pointer conversions.

Comment: @larkey All the function calls in this code have the function call expression of the exact same type as the function being called. in case 0 `*funp` has type `void(void)` and calls `fun0`' of type of `void(void)`, and in case 1 `fn` has type `void(double)` which is the same as fun1's type of `void(double)`.

Comment: @M.M Ian just added the argumentation about to-and-back casting of the function which is why this code is indeed correct!  I'd still would argue that the original code is as well even by future standards as (except for main) no declaration of a function w/o a parameter list is actually happening, but just a typedef.

Comment: @larkey the original code is correct but uses obsolescent feature, which means a future standard might remove that feature (.e.g. `typedef void    funp();` might become illegal)

Comment: @M.M There's a discussion about that, but I could really well think that the final draft will not obsolete this but only declaring actual functions for exactly this reason. But we'll see.

Comment: @larkey personally I doubt `int main()` will ever be disallowed

Comment: @M.M The currenr C2x drafts include proposals to invalidate K&R style definitions, but idk how far reaching they are.

Comment: @M.M A couple of the example code snippets in the latest draft still use `int main()`.